# Transformer equivalent circuit values

Tags: transformer, electric-machine

I was given the following data about a transformer

- 1 \$\phi\$
- 25 kVA
- 220/440
- 60Hz
  gave the following test results

Open circuit test (440V side open)

- 220 V, 9.5 A, 650 W

Short circuit test(220V side shorted)

- 37.5, 55A, 950 W

While the values of the \$R_{CL}\$ and \$X_{ML}\$ are right (74.46 and 24.36 Ohms, respectively), the values \$R_{eqH}\$ and \$X_{eqH}\$ are not. It was solved in class way different from what I did, (sorry I understand that the nomenclature is changed sometimes) so I don't know which way is the valid one.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjyPdf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- What I was told -
  To calculate the values of \$R_eqH\$ from to apply
  \$P=I^2R\$
  and then from the Short circuit test
  \$\frac{950}{55^2}=0.31404\Omega\$

then from the \$V=RI\$,
 \$R=\frac{37.5}{55}=0.681\Omega\$
and then, apply the Pythagorean theorem

\$X_eqH=\sqrt{.681^2+.31404^2}=0.605\Omega\$

(fairly easy)

- What I did
  First I referred the values of the short circuit test to the primary side using the ratio \$\frac{220}{440}\$
  giving the  values
  18.75 V, 110 A and 950 W

then since the 110A are different to the nominal current   \$I_{1N}=25kVA/220=113.63A\$
I again adjusted the values to calculate if the nominal current was applied.
\$\frac{113.63}{110}=1.033\$
and the square is 1.067089,then the final values of
19.35 V, 113.63 A and 1013.73 W

To calculate the final equivalent values required then,

\$\frac{1013.73}{19.35*113.63}=.4608\$,
the angle is 62.55 degress and the sine is .8874

calculate
 \$Z_{sc}=\frac{19.35}{113.63}=.17035\$

and then the values of \$R/X_eqH\$ are
\$R_eqH=.4608*.17035=.0785\Omega\$
\$X_eqH=..8874*.17035=0.1511\Omega\$

that clearly does not match the other values, what did I miss?

Comment: 240 or 440? Make your mind up.

Comment: Short circuit test(220V side shorted)? Make your mind up again!

Comment: Hey bro, its true the first one was a mistake, but this time the information is correct, in the short circuit test it was the 220 V side what was shorted.

Comment: So the short circuit test was with 37.5 volts applied to the secondary 440 volt winding? If so then you need to make that clear in the numbers you quote.

Comment: Nop, these are the results of the tests.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. Which winding was voltage applied to during the short circuit test?